# copytool with md5 sum verification python

Tags: python, copy, md5, checksum, verification

I wrote a program which copies an entire directory tree with lots of files in it. This happens
simultaneously to two destinations. It generates the MD5 sums of each file in the
source tree, dumps it to a txt file and does the same on destinations side and compares
all three sums if they are equal, so that I can be sure every file is copied and
checksum verified.

The problem is that I first recursively copy the whole source tree first and then again 
reading the whole source files for source checksum generation. It would be faster I think
to copy a file and generating the source md5 sum right after copy file by file, so that the source files don't need to be read again.

So my question is how can that done in an efficient and fast way? One copy task
could be 500GB of data and about 40.000 files.

Comment: You *could* read the files and hash them while writing to the copy destination. However I suspect this would be much slower than just copying the file using `shutil` and then hashing them separate from the copy process.

Comment: It would be great if it goes like read once write multiple parallel. I thought if the file is in RAM because it was copied I could generate the source md5 sum right after the copy task without the need to read it again. Question is if this is faster then copying hole tree and then reading again the source. The problem I think is I need to generate first the hole directory tree and then copying the files into the right folders...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this from scratch, check out the third-party rsync port for python @ https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsync.py

Rsync already has this problem solved pretty well.